# Manager wants me to attend a virtual medical appointment at work

Tags: united-states, human-resources, health

I have a telehealth appointment coming up and asked to take the time off work needed to go home for the appointment and then return. This usually isn't an issue with my manager but for some reason he has deflected my asking for the partial sick day/pto and has insisted I attend my appointment in his office since he plans to be out during that time anyways.

Attending such a personal meeting at work already makes me uncomfortable but to make it worse, I know for a fact that you can hear whatever is said in there from the office next door even if the doors are closed. In addition, his recent change in attitude makes me suspicious and feel like he could be recording what is said during my appointment.

I've already told him that I don't want to do that and want to go home for my appointment but he is still deflecting. Do I have enough to make a case with our HR department or is there something else I should do to try and resolve this issue?

If it matters, I'm in the USA.

Some additional details based on comments:

1. I scheduled this about a month in advance when only 5 days is required here.
2. I'm transgender but haven't told them so I doubt they know and are being transphobic.
3. I can't attend from my phone primarily because I have no signal and don't have anywhere private to call from. A car is not private when the appointment may involve taking off clothing for any reason.
4. I'm already looking for another job and may have something lined up that I can leave in a few weeks.
5. I live really close to work.
6. I wouldn't attend a private medical appointment anywhere except my own home or a medical facility.
7. I have had an issue recently were I fainted/passed out and was out sick for 3 days but made it clear that this appointment was unrelated and had been scheduled before I had this issue. I told them it was primarily for a private matter (my HRT/transition; didn't specify to them) but we may discuss the recent issue at the end. The current thought is it was stress related (more reason for me to leave this job).

Comment: What is a "telehealth" appointment? What does that mean/entail? I've never even heard the word.

Comment: It is a virtual medical visit. Instead of going into your doctor's office, you meet with them remotely typically over a video call.

Comment: Do you have a vehicle you can hide in to take this call, yours or someone else's?

Comment: The simple answer to "Can you attend a telehealth appointment at work" is to answer that very unreasonable request with a very simple answer, "absolutely not".  Is your supervisor actually denying your sick leave unless you attend this telehealth appointment in their office? Is it to late to just go into the doctor's office?

Comment: @Andrei This does make a lot of assumptions, that I can not follow just from what OP said. Also Answers don't belong into comments.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you feel your manager is not listening to you, then HR or your manager's boss are your best options. You've earned the PTO, so it's up to you when you take it. Some companies may have policies about timing and requirements for requesting early, but in the end it is your PTO and you can use it how and when you choose.

As an alternative, take the entire day. If your manager isn't cool with the half day, then take the full day. In the future, don't tell your manager why you're taking PTO. Leave it at "I've got some personal stuff to take care of."

Comment: Not always so simple. Taking time off for a doctor's appointment, whether in-person or virtual, would typically be considered "sick leave", which often has much less of a requirement for advance notice than "vacation" or "personal time".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: Always a possibility. Some companies do make that distinction, and typically the requirements for sick leave are much less stringent unless it's extended. I would think a sick leave policy would give OP greater flexibility here.

Comment: This answer assumes only PTO is involved, but the question actually said "sick day/pto". Sick leave isn't more flexible than PTO. The former has to be justified while the latter does not.

Comment: @JonBentley A sick leave is still a leave, however. If you take while in office, you're _not leaving_, and the case becomes even more clear-cut.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, the phrase "not always so simple" when talking about vacation time usually involves talking about how obstinate or authoritarian an employer is about allowing their employees to take time off. With few and very specific exemptions, any kind of PTO should be a notification that the employee needs/wants to take time off work, rather than a request for permission to do so. Many of us in the US know just how backwards asking permission is, sort of like asking permission to go to the bathroom in school. Work isn't daycare, us adults can make decisions for ourselves.

Comment: @computercarguy There is a balance, and a **lot** depends on the company. Software development - as long as no major project timelines are impacted, vacation timing doesn't matter much. But in a retail store, for example, there can be real issues making sure that enough people at each level (managers, cashiers, food prep, inventory/stocking, etc.) are available on any given day. If you have 4 people authorized as store managers and one is out sick (which you can't control) and one made vacation plans weeks in advance (family trip, etc.)...

Comment: you might tell the others they *can't* get vacation right now because if you were down to just 1 then that one would have to work overtime and/or close the store early because there has to be a manager at all times. (Not the case for all retail stores, but just a typical example). In the same case though if all 4 are available then 1 asking for last-minute vacation/personal time would be just fine.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, that's the typical example used to say why taking time off hurts co-workers or the business. The reality of that example is the store is purposefully understaffed to increase profits and to prevent people from taking time off. It's not the employee's fault the store is perpetually understaffed for the sake of the owner's pocketbook. I've worked retail, food service, construction, computer repair, software development and more. I know how this works and it's usually unrealistic to how employees need to handle their lives.

Comment: Don't know about the US (and this is probably state-dependent), but even in countries like France which have regulations generally a lot more favourable to the employee than in the US, one cannot take paid time off whenever they want, it is ultimately the employer's decision, without the constraints set by law (they can say you take one week at specific dates in winter and 4 weeks at specific dates in the summer for instance). Most employers are a lot more flexible and as long as you file early enough you can take whenever you want, but it's not a right by law.

Comment: @computercarguy I respectfully disagree. There are certainly some businesses perpetually understaffed, often in pursuit of profit. But using my example above, if you have 4 people who can fill a given role, and you only *need* 2 on any given day, that seems quite reasonable - having more staff (and managers typically salaried, not hourly) could really hurt the business.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact: I _suspect_ this may be culturally different. I suspect you are German (based on your name), and from what I remember in past conversations _all_ doctor's visits count as sick leave in Germany. However, in several other countries I'm aware of, **elective** appointments (e.g. plastic surgery, as an extremely clear example) do not fall under sick leave. Sick leave in some cultures is defined as an _imminent_ health issue where delaying is not a (recommended) option. I don't know what OP's reason for the appt is, but it might be something that is not imminent.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact, there's a limit as to what can be the employer's decision as to when an employee should/can/is allowed to take time off. https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/167633/74517 Or at least it should be severely limited. It's too bad US laws are usually extremely pro-employer and anti-employee, which is why unions exist. Also, I've worked several places that refused to let people take time off because of perpetual "busy" or "need" for specific employee(s) with certain job description.

Comment: @Flater Actually, not German - 3rd generation American with Polish and Russian background! Names are a funny thing. But in any case, I could definitely see (in the USA) someone taking a 1/2 day of sick leave for a doctor's appointment. I could also see some employees saying make that "personal time" and others (the good ones) saying - take an hour and don't worry about it. There is a lot of variety in how employers handle these things. Laws set a minimum, official employer policies ("Employee handbook") is the next step, but in the end it all depends on how a company runs. Some are **much**

Comment: better than others. Timing matters - and a good employer (many aren't) can handle things well and a reasonable employee (not all...) will know how/when to ask. No "single answer" for all situations.

Answer (score 112):

I generally tend towards being pretty paranoid about work privacy and health issues, but since no one else has suggested this yet, is it possible that your manager thinks he is genuinely doing you a favor? He may think that he's being kind and saving you PTO, without realizing your privacy concerns or that his office isn't very soundproof. And his insistence may be just a cultural thing, like with gift-giving where the recipient is expected to refuse symbolically and the giver is expected to keep insisting until they accept.

If this is the case (as opposed to your manager having malicious intent) you can just tell him that his office isn't soundproof and you are uncomfortable about the privacy and charging the company for personal business. If you believe I'm just being optimistic, then Joel's answer is correct.

Comment: This is also the first thing that came to mind and I am usually pretty pessimistic, so be moderately appreciative just in case he is that rare "genuinely good person that didn't think through the situation fully".

Comment: The manager could be thinking that they are doing OP a favor, but after OP pushed back and they stuck with it this possibility becomes less likely. At least, unless OP and their manager have massive communication issues or the manager has no emotional intelligence at all...

Comment: I like this answer and up voted it, but it's more for other situations. I'm with @xLeitix in that this manager insisting on the OP use their office after the OP stated their reservations generally means the manager is not trying to do a favor be being manipulative, instead. And worse, the manager may become mad that their manipulation isn't working.

Comment: @xLeitix My wife is Persian, and the culture from Iran has a different view.  If you say "no" it isn't because you don't want it, it's because you are offering the person a chance to show how generous they are by giving them the chance to offer again.  In the USA, we don't do that, we say "oh, that seems like too much trouble" instead of "no".  Likewise any host offers way too much to a guest in this culture, and the host expects the guest to say no.  So if the host over-offers, they don't have to deliver.  It is nearly insane, but that's how that culture works.  EI is following it, for them.

Answer (score 58):

Send an email:

> Hello $boss.
>
> I really appreciate your offer to use your office for my telehealth appointment on $date. However, a doctor's appointment means I might have to take my clothes off for diagnosis and I really don't feel comfortable doing that in *any* office in our company. I'm sure it's against some regulation and HR would probably have a heart attack just thinking about it.
>
> So I will be out of the office on $date between $starttime and $endtime.

If your boss *really* is weird enough to continue to insist on this, forward the email and your bosses response to HR.

Comment: How do you know OP might need to take his clothes off? Or, are you suggesting OP lie about this?

Comment: I have no idea... neither has the OP. That's why I suggested to say "I might have to". It always is a possibility, you never know what a doctor may want to see to diagnose you correctly.

Comment: To be fair, I'm transgender and this is my first appointment since starting HRT so anything is possible and makes it even more uncomfortable for me to attend at work. I'm not out to anyone there and haven't told them that's what it is for (none of their business). It isn't out of the question my doctor would want to review the physical changes.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you should say anything other than that you're not comfortable doing telehealth from the workplace. Especially since the more reasons you provide, the more likely the other party is to come up with "solutions" - ie. use my office etc.

Comment: I wouldn't mention clothes.  "The doctor may have to use my phone camera for diagnosis, and I'd be uncomfortable doing that in the office" might be a bit less direct.

Comment: @Yakk - Part of the point of this response is to tactically make $boss uncomfortable enough to realize they're asking for something inappropriate. I can't imagine a telehealth procedure asking for patients to remove much clothing, but that's none of $bosses business anyway.

Comment: An email phrased this way is asking for trouble. Imagine the next holiday party where the boss gets drunk and starts telling OP in front of everyone “honey, remember that time when you told me how you feel uncomfortable getting undressed in my office?” One can imagine other unexpected ways in which OP’s words could be taken out of context and used against them somehow. Basically, a good workplace rule of thumb is to never discuss with your boss anything mentioning yourself being in a state of undress.

Comment: With that said, the general strategy of this answer seems valid. I’d replace the stuff about taking your clothes off with something along the lines of “I really appreciate your offer to use your office for my telehealth appointment. However, our work premises do not meet my privacy needs for this appointment. So I will be out of the office on [etc]”

Comment: @DavidWaterworth I don’t see why OP should need to discuss being uncomfortable with anything. Their comfort or lack of it is equally none of the boss’s business, and discussing it can also invite discussion about “solutions” to the discomfort. See my comment above for an alternative suggested phrasing.

Comment: @DanRomik true, good point!

Answer (score 13):

**First call your doctor's office and ask if *they'd* be ok with it**

Your doctor's office may be really paranoid about patient privacy and may refuse your appointment if taken in your workplace. It's worth checking with them first. If they say it's a "no go", you have ammunition with your employer. If on the other hand they give it a green-light, don't mention this to your boss--fall back on your own personal hesitation, which is fully valid. I for one would *not* be ok with this kind of thing.

I say this because doctors offices I've worked with seem pretty paranoid about telehealth from a policy standpoint (particularly with regard to their own HIPAA compliance as a healthcare provider) and so they may well say "no way!" to this idea, again giving you some pretty big ammunition with your boss.

*Note: don't tell your boss you're going to do this. Just do it.*

**Also I'd check laws in your area**

IANAL but it sounds like your employer *may* be doing something illegal by trying to force you to take a doctors appointment onsite. Maybe. Again, IANAL...

**Note that this approach could backfire**

Only use this approach if you don't feel comfortable (or can't afford to) take the more direct approach of saying "I don't feel comfortable with that" and not backing down no matter what. Personally I prefer a direct approach when I can, as giving reasons can give the other person leverage for argumentation. But if you can't or don't want to draw a line in the sand with your boss, this approach may provide you cover, assuming your boss takes the doctor's word as final.

Comment: I can confirm that there are doctors that won't do telehealth appointments unless you can assure them of privacy on your end for legal reasons.

Comment: @BSMP I'm surprised--generally it's your choice who you bring with you to a doctor's appointment, thus it should be your choice who is around on a teleappointment.

Comment: I would be reluctant to take this approach.  The boss might say something like "just tell them it's your home office if they ask."  I would not give any openings for objections.  Just state that I'm not comfortable doing the appointment from the office and I will be going home to do it.  As in not asking you for permission, telling you what is happening.  Especially since getting fired would probably not be a major issue.

Comment: Yeah, it's a risk and I don't disagree. I personally would take your approach. Mine is only for people who aren't ready to simply say "no".

Comment: What difference does the doctor's opinion make? The OP doesn't need the doctor's permission to give a "no" to their employer? Granted, sometimes it's nice to have a scapegoat...

Comment: @spuck Exactly that--a scapegoat. I agree, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Updated to include notes about how this approach could backfire and when to use it.

Answer (score 10):

To me, it seems like he thinks (actually fears) you have job interview at another company, that's why he brings you in this awkward situation. While I don't necessarily think he would be spying on you, neither listening at the door, nor recording, he knows that nobody would like to have a job interview in the current bosses office and a doctor's appointment is the usual excuse for job interviews. Since your reaction was rather strong in refusing the offer, he feels his point proven, you "failed" the test.

You were talking about "recent change in attitude", so I feel he might be afraid of losing a valuable employee without replacement. What led to this change in attitude, has there been a specific situation, e.g. an important coworker leaving, you voicing general concerns about your tasks/position or any other situation that could imply things are not going great? Is there anything that could lead him to these kind of thoughts and how irreplaceable are you to the department/company?

Stress that it's a health-related issue, while not going into details and also voice your concerns regarding privacy and discussing medical issues in the office. Hopefully it's just a misunderstanding that does not require escalation, but if not - the other answers have a lot of good approaches including HR or the managers' boss.

Comment: "You were talking about "recent change in attitude", so I feel he might be afraid of losing a valuable employee without replacement." I think it's also entirely possible that they've figured out that the OP is transexual, and have started treating them differently as a result.